# Redux simulated component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What is the most efficient way in (functional) React to update a component when a variable changes value?

A piece of code somewhere in the program (over which I have no control) changes a variable e.g. an array in a "Redux" compatible way (i.e. a new reference is returned).

I would like to simulate Redux's `useSelector` without having to have to use Redux.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the component means you need useState, Not sure what exatcly you are looking for, But if you want to update the component without much Props drilling, then i will suggest you to look into the Context-API on react.

This way you can have control like redux, without redux.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: with Redux I can dispatch an action from anywhere in the program (not necessarily from within a component). This way I can take advantage of OOP to separate the part of the program that alters the state from the one that displays information in components. The only way I can alter the context using ```useContext``` is by returning a setter via hooks. Which really doesn't help much....

Comment: Ideally I am trying to "dispatch" an action that alters a piece of global state and the corresponding components that use that particular piece of state to update (without using redux and the flux pattern)

Comment: You can dispatch the action on Context-API aswell, just like Redux. 
Here my old Context api example. Please view this one. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-9sokc?file=/src/login.jsx